# Ping to Laravel Homestead is Fine but Web Connection Refused

Tags: laravel-5, vagrant, homestead

I just set up a homestead on my Windows 10 machine. Everything looks fine but page is not loading. I am getting `connection refused` on my browser.

I have asked this on `Laracasts` with details

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/servers/ping-to-homestead-is-fine-but-connection-refused#reply=495171

I think it is a minor issue but don't know where and what to look for.

My `Homestead.yaml` file:

```
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: d:/DATA/SourceCodes/laravel
      to: /home/vagrant/code

sites:
    - map: myapp.test
      to: /home/vagrant/code/myapp/public

databases:
    - homestead
```

Answer (score 0):

at many times I found that modern browsers refuses to connect to urls that is ending with some unknown extensions for security reasons, so maybe its the url.

- add "myapp.test" to Homestead.yaml file > `sites: -map: myapp.test`.
- make sure you did edit hosts added line`192.168.10.10 myapp.test`

*another possibilities:*

- if you are using antivirus or any internet security program on your
  host system: disable it for a while and test.
- if you use proxy for your internet connection, add myapp.test as an exception or disable the proxy for a while

Comment: tried both `www.myapp.test` and `myapp.test` (changes were made on `Homestead.yaml` and `hosts` file as well. Result is still same `connection refused`.

Comment: I updated another possible problems I hope they help

Comment: don't have proxy and disabling antivirus doesn't work either

Comment: when using windows I usually suspect browsers, antiviruses and all other things than vagrant itself, I assume you are sure you did setup the environment correctly as mentioned in laravel documentation, no harm anyway if you tried to access your app from incognito mode (so no security plug-in interfere).
these are almost all cases I contradicted before. If I remembered any thing else I'll comeback to you. good luck and please update me when solved.

Comment: You are right. I suspected that too. I tried your last suggestion also in incognito but getting the same result.

Comment: did you try pinging your url?

Comment: yes pinging url works. However it refuses connection from browser

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a problem with nginx. Try to login to homestead with ssh and check if nginx is running. I had the same problem after upgrading Homestead when my nginx config file was throwing an error (check your config with `nginx -t`)